# How to connect to a newly created Oracle database on SQL developer

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration, oracle19c

How do u connect to a newly created oracle database using SQL developer. Do I need to configure the TNS names.ora file?

Comment: This link will be useful for you https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-0DE0C9F4-8800-4142-A755-14B2FAA6624F.htm#ADMQS12420

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your listener process is running on the server (check on the server with command `lsnrctl status` if needed), you can connect using JDBC which is the default in SQL Developer.

Provide the hostname (or IP), the listener port and a user+password and you should be fine.

You can also connect through TNS, using the Connection Type = TNS in the SQL Dev connection dropdown list.
Only in this mode (and when using SQL*Plus for example), you will need a local Oracle client and your tnsnames.ora file will have to be appended with an entry for the Oracle instance you want to connect to.